# Why didn't my solution for differential equation work?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I was doing my Calculus test today and came across the following problem:

> Show that $y=(e^x)\cdot\sin(2x)$ is a solution to $y''-2y'+5y = 0$.

Clearly, it can be easily but tediously be solved by just plugging in the derivatives and simplifying which in the end I had to do. However, first I tried solving the D.E. using the general solution $a\cdot e^{(1+2i)x}+b\cdot e^{(1-2i)x}$ and showing that this solution was equivalent to $e^x\cdot\sin(2x)$ but I couldn't do it. Where did I go wrong? Essentially I am asking how is this done without just taking the derivatives and a lot of algebra. Thanks in advance!

Edit: Thanks for the answers, I guess my problem was I assumed a and b to be real.

Comment: $a\cdot e^{(1+2i)x}+b\cdot e^{(1-2i)x} = \frac {a+b}{2} e^{x} \cos 2x + \frac {a-b}{2i} e^{x} \sin 2x$  if $a$ and $b$ are complex conjugates of one another, then you have real solutions.  So what are the correct $a, b$ for your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that

$$\sin (2x) = \frac{e^{2i x} - e^{-2ix}}{2i}.$$

Thus,

$$e^x \sin(2x) = \frac{1}{2i} e^{(1+2i)x} - \frac{1}{2i} e^{(1-2i)x}.$$

You wrote down a general solution, but you needed to find the specific values of $a$ and $b$ which gave rise to the particular solution which was given.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{e^{-2ix} - e^{2ix}}{2i}$ is $\sin(2x)$; this is a bizarre fact you can get from Taylor series. It's related to the hyperbolic sine function. Setting $a = -\frac{1}{2i}$ and $b = \frac{1}{2i}$, your solution gives $e^x\sin(2x)$.